# Add Model Attribute to an instance if it doesn't have one

Tags: python, django, python-2.7, model

i've recently added a optional costs Model option to Estimate creation(finance).
Now that, when i'm trying to edit statement, the statements created after the optional costs updation, updates successfully. but the previous statements that doesn't have the optional costs model attribute fails on updating.

this is what i've tried

```
if hasattr(instance,"optional_amount"):
  optional_estimate_amounts = optional_estimate_amounts_formset.save(commit=False)
  for f in optional_estimate_amounts:
    f.estimate = instance
    f.save()
  for obj in optional_estimate_amounts_formset.deleted_objects:
    obj.delete()
else:
  for optional_estimate_amounts in optional_estimate_amounts_formset:
    optional_amount_description = optional_estimate_amounts[
      'optional_amount_description']
    optional_amount = optional_estimate_amounts['optional_amount']
    OptionalEstimateAmounts(
      estimate=data,
      optional_amount_description=optional_amount_description,
      optional_amount=optional_amount
    ).save()
```

currently it throws type error. 
I'm wondering how to create a new optional amount model attribute to an existing estimate instance if it doesn't have one when trying to edit estimate?

Comment: If you get an error, you should show it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

NeverMind, setAttr() was the thing i had been looking for. if hasAttr() returns false, use setAttr to add that attribute